# Elegantly Determining System Architecture Within Perl

Tags: perl, architecture

I'm looking for a simple way to determine whether a system is 32- or 64-bit from within Perl 5. I have read the `perlvar` manual page backwards and forwards, and have not discovered a variable that contains the system's CPU architecture (the CPU architecture Perl was compiled for will come close enough). This is the closest I have come:

```
chomp (my $arch = `uname -m`);
```

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of determining this; I hate relying on backtick expressions, as they are both a bottleneck, tend to be insecure, and often (this example especially) break cross-platform compatibility. There is no reason Perl shouldn't already have this information available.

Comment: What are you doing based on this?  If you are worried about cross-platform compatibility, it seems like it would be something very specific that would greatly influence the appropriate answer.

Comment: @ytsh: I'm not worried about cross-platform compatibility in this particular script; I was just outlining why I didn't like using backticks. You are right, though.

Comment: Still, what are you doing differently based on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [`Config`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config) module.

Maybe checking whether `$Config{'archname64'}` is set would be sufficient.

Comment: This might be one of those "what do you really want to know?" questions. For struct en/decoding you might want to inspect `$Config{alignbytes}` or `$Config{byteorder}`; if you're interested in integer range you might want `$Config{intsize}` or `$Config{ivsize}` (which I think is relatively new), etc. etc.

Answer (score 8):

[`Sys::Info::OS->bitness`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Info::OS#bitness) method will determine "bitness" of your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a CPAN module such as https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::CheckOS .

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module which provides a `uname` function similar to the uname utility.

```
use POSIX ();

my ($sysname, $nodename, $release, $version, $machine) = POSIX::uname;
```

Or, in your case  :

```
my $arch = (POSIX::uname)[4];
```