# How can I know if I am running in a 64bits or a 32bits linux from within a perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, architecture

I don't want to directly access the shell (for example to use uname).  I am looking for a fast-forward way to detect the architecture (only if it is 32 or 64 bits), once I know I am on linux.

Comment: This question specifies Perl and *not* shelling out to use uname. Everything on that "duplicate" is all about using uname from the shell. Doesn't seem like an exact duplicate at all to me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224082/elegantly-determining-system-architecture-within-perl/3224559#3224559

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 separate questions you could be asking:

Note for all that there's not a single magic "64-bit", there's lots of different things that could mean.

1. What's the hardware? -- `/proc/cpuinfo` contains this info in a hard to parse manner. You basically need to have a table of what the different CPUs are. I believe you'll get numbers bigger than 32 in an "address sizes" if the kernel is 64-bit, though.
2. What's the OS/kernel? -- I believe `use POSIX;` and inspecting `(POSIX::uname())[4]` is the canonical answer, but `-d /lib64`, `-d /usr/lib64` being true is also a good indicator.
3. Is this a 64-bit perl? -- `use Config;` and look at `$Config{archname}`, `$Config{myarchname}`, `$Config{use64bitint}`, or some other variable in Config that matches up to what you believe "64 bit" means.

Comment: This is good, and there are further shades of distinction in Config -- for example it's possible to build a perl on a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit compiler that has 32-bit IVs for compatibility. In that case, `longsize` might be 8, `ivsize` 4, and `use64bitint` undef :)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e 'use Config; print $Config{longsize}';
```

Will return 8 bytes on a 64 bit implementation of Perl, and 4 bytes on a 32 bit implementation of Perl.

If you want to actually check the hardware, you'll have to either do a uname or check for something that only reasonably exists on a 64 bit machine (like /lib64).  Note that it is often not very useful to know the hardware support for 64 bits if you are stuck in a 32 bit application.

Comment: Neither `uname` or the absence of `lib64` tells you anything about the hardware, only about the OS.  And knowing the OS supports 64-bits is VERY useful, because you can spawn 64-bit processes.

Comment: If you imply that one can use the hardware without going through the OS, then what flavour of Linux are you using?  Still, I guess you could grab cpuinfo and determine the hardware architecture, but its utility might not mean that much if you're using an OS that doesn't give you access to it.

Comment: I mean it's entirely possible to have 64-bit hardware yet every indicator you mentioned give a 32-bit result.  Your answer would be mostly correct if you replace "hardware" with "OS" and "machine" with "environment"... the last sentence would still be wrong though -- having a 32-bit application does not restrict you from spawning 64-bit processes if the environment is 64-bit.